# React Native can't find native method

Tags: android, react-native

I am new in React Native, here is my problem:
I want to start an activity by calling NATIVE code from REACT NATIVE on a button click.

I am getting an error, says on the JS console 'cannot read property \'startActivity\'of undefined.

```
  ...MORE CODE...
  import ActivityStarter from './ActivityStarter'
  ...MORE CODE...

                <Button
            onPress={() => ActivityStarter.startActivity()}
            title='Login'  />
```

on the Java end:

public class ActivityStarterModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

```
public ActivityStarterModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "ActivityStarter";
}

@ReactMethod
public void startActivity() {
    ReactApplicationContext context = getReactApplicationContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DashBoardScreen.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your import for ActivityStarter ( it should be imported from NativeModules).
2. Check MainApplication.java to see if you've included your custom module in getPackages() method.
3. Try to log NativeModules.ActivityStarter and see if it has your methods or it is undefined.

If these steps don't solve your problem, then please post your sample project for testing.